# call facebook ajax from my facebook app

Tags: jquery, ajax, facebook, cross-domain, jsonp

I recently created a facebook app to manage friendlists. I can create and delete them, with surprise I noticed the FB API doesn't offer any method to RENAME a friendlist.

In facebook it's possible to rename a friendlist. With Firebug I saw that when I rename a list via facebook this page is called:

https://www.facebook.com/friends/ajax/lists.php

METHOD: POST

Parameters:

> __a   1
>
> __user    myUID
>
> fb_dtsg   AQBcx3kd
>
> flid  myFriendListID
>
> phstamp   1658166991205110710078
>
> rename    ztest456

Source: 
fb_dtsg=AQBcx3kd&flid=myFriendListID&rename=ztest456&_*user=myUID&*_a=1&phstamp=1658166991205110710078

So in my working app I tried to build by ajax function, like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://www.facebook.com/friends/ajax/lists.php",
    data: "flid=" + myFriendListID + "&rename=" + newName + "&__user=" + uid + "&__a=1",
    success: function(msg){

    },
    error: function(msg){
        console.log("Error: " + msg);
    }
}).done(function( msg ) {
    //console.log("Feedback: " + msg);
});
```

What I get from facebook is ERROR. I read in stackoverflow that is possibly to make cross domain ajax requests by using JSONP or allowing in jquery $.support.cors = true; (I enabled cors support but still it doesn't work).

Also a problem is that the phpstamp and fb_dtsg change every time (fb_dtsg maybe same session, phpstamp seems to be increased by 1 for every request).

Honestly I don't know what to use, seems quite a challenge (coz of course, no support from facebook is provided) so here I ask your support ;)

Comment: pffff thx to whoever downvoted my question without even giving feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have access to the ajax files on Facebook's domain. Simple as that. You can use the Graph API to create and delete lists. Documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/FriendList/)